# Counter for bowls of ramen?

Tags: counters, food

I'm writing a skit but I need a counter for bowls of ramen. ひとつ　ふたつ somehow sounds weird. Is there a counter for bowls?

Answer (score 6):

Quote from [数え方の辞典](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4095052015/) (which I have introduced here [before](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9714/why-are-movies-video-clips-counted-with-%E6%9C%AC/9718#9718)):

> ラーメン（拉麺）
>
> 数え方：本、杯（はい）、丁（ちょう）、玉（たま）
>
> スープ・具・麺（めん）を椀（わん）や丼に盛ると「杯」で数えます。飲食店で注文を受け、景気付けに店員が「ラーメン一丁」のように「丁」で注文を数えることがあります。ばらばらの麺は「本」、1食分の麺の分量は「玉」で表します。

Comment: I take it 玉 would mostly be used in the sense of 替え玉{かえだま}？

Comment: @nkjt うどん[玉]{たま}にも「うどん[２玉]{ふたたま}買ってきて～」とかいいます。　http://fujimuraya.com/shopping/shop/udon/image/m0100l.jpg　←普通、これ位の大きさのが[１玉]{ひとたま}。ゆでてある「和そば」や、焼きそば・ラーメン用のゆで麺も、よく「玉」で数えます

Comment: A very misleading answer for most J-leaners.  One would need a near-native level proficiency to make use of it.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya どう、どう・・・。(←　I mean, "Easy", not "How")

Comment: まあ、OPがコンテクストを提示してないし、レストラン/ラーメン屋での会話だとも書いてないし・・・「一日にラーメン３杯食えます」って言ってるかもしれないし・・しょうがないよね～汗　^^;

Answer (score 4):

How significant is it when a Japanese learner says a word or phrase sounds weird? ひとつ、ふたつ、みっつ, etc. is by far the most often used way of ordering ramen in a restaurant.

玉 is the counter for the noodle part of a ramen, not for the entire bowl of ramen with noodles, soup, toppings, etc.

杯 is the counter for the whole thing --- noodles, soup and toppings.  Some people use this counter for ordering ramen but it is much less common to do so than to use ひとつ、ふたつ、みっつ.

丁 is the counter almost exclusively used by the waiter/waitress to tell the kitchen how many ramen has just been ordered.

本 is almost irrelevant to the original question because it is only used to count the strands of noodle.

Comment: Come to think of it... we use ひとつ、ふたつ、みっつ when ordering coffee, udon, yakisoba, sushi, cheeseburger, french fries and... just about anything! (...except kushi-age and yakitori, maybe?)

Comment: “How significant is it when a Japanese learner says a word or phrase sounds weird?”  What is this sentence supposed to mean?  It sounds a little insulting.

Comment: @Tokyo どう、どう・・・